# Playing iTunes library songs on HomePod with Siri

Tags: music, siri, itunes-match, homepod

We've had a lot of problems over the years trying to play music via Siri on our HomePods. I have iTunes Match, and virtually all of the music is in my account. It used to be that saying "Hey Siri, Play " was enough, but that broke a long time ago -- Siri responds "I can't find  in your Apple Music library". I recently discovered that if I add on "in my iTunes library" it works.

But my wife is still having problems with it, and we just tested it back to back with the same album name -- despite all being part of the same home and family sharing, is Siri treating my voice separately and only allowing access to iTunes Match content from my voice? If so, is there a way to fix that?